# Is there an algorithm/way to find out how different (or the minimum distance between) 2 list orders?

Tags: list, sorting, distance, levenshtein-distance

I have a bunch of items I want to rate in a specific order. For example:

```
["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4", "Person5"]
```

Which can be ordered like this:

```
["Person4", "Person5", "Person3", "Person1", "Person2"]
```

Given 2 different orders of the same list, is there a way to quantify how difference they are?
I know Levenshtein distance exists for strings, and I'm looking for something similar.

My ideal measurement for distance would be the minimum number of switches between two adjacent items required to change one list to the other - but I'm open to other algorithms if you think they're better.

The answer I'm looking for is an algorithm (and preferably, a [Python] implementation) to perform this kind of measurement (fast).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To quantify how "different" two strings are, as you already noted, you can use [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), which is [implemented in this library](https://maxbachmann.github.io/Levenshtein/):

```
pip install levenshtein
```

```py
>>> import Levenshtein
>>> Levenshtein.distance("lewenstein", "levenshtein")
2
```

To determine how "different" two lists are, you could assign each value in the list to a Unicode character.

```py
import Levenshtein

def list_distance(A, B):
    # Assign each unique value of the list to a unicode character
    unique_map = {v:chr(k) for (k,v) in enumerate(set(A+B))}
    
    # Create string versions of the lists
    a = ''.join(list(map(unique_map.get, A)))
    b = ''.join(list(map(unique_map.get, B)))

    return Levenshtein.distance(a, b)

A = ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4", "Person5"]
B = ["Person4", "Person5", "Person3", "Person1", "Person2"]
list_distance(A, B)
```

returns 4.

This works by making a unique mapping to arbitrary Unicode characters, for example:

- the list A to the string `'\x03\x02\x01\x00\x04'` and
- the list B to the string `'\x00\x04\x01\x03\x02'`,

before taking the Levenshtein distance of the two strings.